# Can I execute multiple test cases in same browser using Selenium

Tags: selenium

I have multiple usernames and passwords. I need to validate all that test data in one Chrome window. And I need to check whether it's working fine or not. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

```
public class Wrappers extends GenericWrappers {

    public String browserName;
    public String dataSheetName;
    protected static WebDriver Browser_Session;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {
        startResult();
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        loadObjects();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        test = startTestCase(testCaseName, testDescription);
        test.assignCategory(category);  
        invokeApp("Chrome");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite() {
        endResult();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        unloadObjects();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        endTestcase();  
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "fetchData")
    public Object[][] getData() {
        return DataInputProvider.getSheet(dataSheetName);
    }
}

public class Login extends PEFWrappers {

    @Parameters("browser")
    @BeforeClass()

    public void setValues(String browser) {
        browserName = browser;
        testCaseName = "TC001 - Login";
        testDescription = "Login and Submit a form";
        category = "smoke";
        dataSheetName = "TC_001";
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "fetchData")
     public void loginPEF(String LoginId, String Password) throws InterruptedException
    {   
        new LoginPage(driver, test)
        .enterLoginID(LoginId)
        .enterPassword(Password)
        .clickLogin();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible, What is your trial code for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the set of credentials in the **DataProvider** method
For eg

```
@DataProvider(name="fetchData")
public Object[][] getData()
{
   Object [][] myData = {{"user1","pwd1"},
                        {"user2","pwd2"}};
   return myData;
}
```

Here I have given 2 sets of username/Password So the test will be executed 2 times with 2 different sets of credentials.

Here you are taking values from external file. So just enter username and password in rows. Test will repeat as many times as the number of rows available in the datasheet